# Windows share not respecting NTFS permissions?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share, ntfs

I have a Windows server and so far shared a folder `D:\AAA` as "ShareRW" with full share permissions ("Everyone - Full") and some stricter NTFS permissions as required on and below that folder; for example, *UserX* has full access to `D:\AAA\BBB`, read access to `D:\AAA\CCC` and cannot even see `D:\AAA\DDD` (because it has inheritance disabled and explicit rights only to other users). I checked on the server that the effective rights of *UserX* are indeed as desired.

Now I wanted to add the option to "mount -r" the same content and therefore created a second share with a different name "ShareRO" on the same folder and with only "Everyone - Read" permissions (and of course with the same old NTFS permisssions).

Now my *UserX* does both `NET USE W: \\server\ShareRW` and `NET USE R: \\server\ShareRO`. I expected R: to look the same as W:, except that writing/changing is not allowed. But reality begged to differ:

- The user can change stuff in `W:\BBB`, they can read stuff in `W:\CCC`, and they do not even see that `W:\DDD` exists
- The user can read stuff in `R:\BBB`, they can read stuff in `R:\CCC`, **but they see that `R:\DDD` exists and some metadata (size, creation date)** though they cannot open it.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You miss the setting "Enable access-based enumeration" on the second share properties. It's a per-share settings.

See that as an example;

[image]